# PHP error [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php script that searches a database based on some filters and echoes back the number of results. I request this file with ajax, to be able to display the number of results the search returns right after the user changes some selects.

This works just fine on a local host, but it doesn't on a production server, and since I had no idea what was wrong (no visible errors) I called the php script directly, to see whether it has any errors or not. what I get is `<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
[an error occurred while processing this directive]`

The php includes 2 files, the database connection info, and some initialization stuff. I used relative path, and both files are at the correct location, with correct permissions.

I checked the error log, and since there's nothing in there. I googled this, but nothing concrete came up, and ATM I have no idea how to get around this. 
Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Enable Error Printing in PHP**

In order to find out the bug, enable errors for your PHP.

From http://www.bradino.com/php/error-reporting/:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

If that doesn't work, edit php.ini (see http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and set:

```
display_errors=1
```

If you don't know where your php.ini is located use:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And locate *"configuration file (php.ini) path"*. For visual instructions, see: http://www.php-scripts.com/20050909/8/

**Step 2: Debug your Apache / Web Server Log**

If you still don't get any errors in PHP, the problem has to be with web server:

If you are using Apache, locate `access.log` and `error.log` and see if they contain messages related to this issue.

Hint: `tail -f xxx.log` allows you to track changes in a log in real-time (very useful for debugging).

Comment: Did you both enable error printing AND check server logs? Did you make sure display_errors was enabled? Sometimes the only way to do this is to change the value in php.ini

Comment: Access logs reveal nothing, only that the php was accessed via POST, and I have no access to server logs.

Answer (score 2):

According to info [I have seen elsewhere](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?11101-SHTML-Wrapper-500-Server-Error-moving-to-a-new-box-helps), this can be caused by incorrect file permissions on your scripts.  They may not be permitted to be other-writable on the server.  The forum thread below suggests that permissions like `666` or `777` will cause this. If that's what you have, you will need to `chmod 644` or `chmod 755` your scripts on the production host.

Comment: Like I said, I have the correct permissions :) everything is 755

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the apache log.

Comment: Then it'll be hard to detect the problem. Htaccess could be the cause (disabled but using ModRewrite? other syntax errors). Can't you contact the hosting and ask for logs? Otherwise, try commenting out all of the code and then uncommenting block by block and narrowing the scope of the problem.

Comment: The site is a Prestashop derivative, and the .htaccess file was automatically generated, and includes mostly url rewriting rules.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure that ModRewrite is enabled on that server?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on

# URL rewriting rules
</IfModule> so yes, it's on

Answer (score 0):

It's all about file permission issue, Now it's working for me...

Folder permission must be 755 other permissions like (752, 753, 756, and 777) cause limitation and will not work..

File permission must be 644 other permissions like (642, 643, 646 and 647) cause limitation and will not work..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was caused by hashtag in comments like this:

```
<!--#featured-item -->
```

I solved this issue by removing hashtags in comments

```
<!--featured-item -->
```